# How to share single database connection between multiple packages

Tags: go

I have two packages named client and worker. I want to share same ssdb, mysql and redis connection with both the packages.
One more similar problem that i am facing to share auth between these two packages.

```
app
  -> client pkg
  -> worker pkg
  main.go (contains auth as global variable)
```

Can anyone please suggest me the best way to implement these two things ?

Comment: Which approaches have you tried? What problems did you encounter or do you anticipate?

Comment: I have made a separate package for db and have a global variable for connection pool. Then import it in both packages. But is it the right way to handle it? And one more thing again in future if i come across same situation again.. i will have to add a new package each time ?

Comment: Create a global package containing the configurations and import it in your packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do this and each approach has pros and cons and it really depends on what you are doing. One easy way to do this is to have a third package with the DB connection and import it from the other two packages and from the main package.

```
app
  -> client pkg // import "app/global"
  -> worker pkg // import "app/global"
  -> global pkg // Contains ssdb and auth as global variables
  main.go
```

Another approach that might be better depending on what you are doing is to have the functions on the `client` and `worker` packages accept a db connection as a parameter and from `main.go` initialize the db and pass it as a parameter when you call a function that needs it.

It depends on what you are doing but for big projects it's easier to maintain if you just have one package doing all your db operations and you access it from all the places you need to do something. That way you don't have to worry about this issue because only one package has to worry about the db connection even if several packages use it.

**Edit:**

The problem with global variables is that they can be modified at the same time from everywhere in your project and it can introduce race conditions, but there is nothing wrong in using them when this is not an issue.

In this case, you are just setting the value once, when you connect to the DB and then just use the object.

You mentioned you want to have another package for the auth, I recommend just having one package and having in it everything you need to access from more than one package, in this case ssdb and auth.

Comment: I like to make a different package all together and import in both the packages. But the problem is i have read that keeping global variables is not a good practice. One more thing it was just db.. same thing will have to do with auth also as my both packages requires auth. Again i will have to make a new package for auth and keep auth it as a global variable. This approach will end up so many packages in this project.

Comment: @NidhiAgarwal Please see the edit on my answer. Also, what type of variable is auth and what do you do with it? If you write from different goroutines you will need to make it thread safe

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am one more doubt. So i am moving all my common packages to a global package. But for example i export my conn from sql package (global -> sql -> sql.go) and use it in some other package. I may need some struct type also from actual sql package to define variables here. How do i export them from global?

Comment: @NidhiAgarwal I don't think it's wrong if you just use those structs directly from the sql package, and just leave in global the DB connection, but if you want to have it all on the same package you need to create a new exported type type in your global package, and then convert them to the sql type when you use them in a function that needs them. You can do this by creating a new type using the sql struct as the base: `type MyStruct sql.StructName` and read this to learn about type conversions: `type MyStruct sql.StructName`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach that is not always obvious to new Go developers, is a little elbow grease to implement but not terribly
complex, and usually works fine in beginner apps:

```
app
    client // imports storage
    worker // imports storage
    config // all environment-related config goes here
    storage   // storage-engine-generic interface to the packages below it
        ssdb  // all ssdb-specific code here
        mysql // all mysql-specific code here
        redis // ditto
```

It uses package variables.  If you're paranoid about an accidental write to an exported package variable, you can avoid the problem by using unexported package variables.  Take advantage of the
limited definition of Exported Identifiers in Go (see [language
specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)).

In `main`, call

```
config.Init(configfile)
storage.Init()
```

Define your `config.Init` function to read the config file and set package variables to the connection information for your
databases.  If you're using unexported package variables, then allow public read-only access through exported functions.  Otherwise you may be able to skip the functions, depending on what other features you want.

In `storage`, your `Init` function calls

```
ssdb.Init()
mysql.Init()
redis.Init()
```

Then also in `storage` you'll have public functions that `client` and `server` use that aren't specific to a storage engine, such as

```
func GetImage(id string) ([]byte) {
    return mysql.GetImage(id)
}
```

or whatever is appropriate for your application.  The `storage` level of abstraction may or may not be worth it for you depending on how you change your app in the future.  You decide whether it's worth investing in it.

In `mysql` package, you import `config`, and you have something like

```
var db *sql.DB
func Init() {
    getDb()
}
func getDb() (*sql.DB) {
    if db == nil {  // or something
        config.Log.Println("Opening db connection to mysql")
        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", config.MysqlConnectionString())
        // do something with err, possibly have a retry loop
    }
    return db
}
func GetImage(id string) ([]byte)
     db := getDb()
     // ...
```

The functions in the mysql package can use the `db` unexported package variable, but other packages cannot.

Using an unexported package variable with exported-function read-only access is not a terrible practice or particularly complex.  That said, it's usually unecessary.  If `db` were the exported package variable `Db`, would you suddenly type

```
mysql.Db, _ = sql.Open("mysql", "LEEERRROOYYYYY!!!!")
```

in your `client` code (and also decide to import `mysql` and `sql` to do it) and then deploy to production?  Why would you be more likely to do that than to intentionally break any other part of your code?

Note that if you just typed

```
mysql.Db = "LEEERRROOYYYYYY!!!!"
```

Your application would fail to compile because of a type mismatch.

Comment: Jeeennnkiiinnnsssss